# Rails: Where is message digest of sessions using default CookieStore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, cookies

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353861/security-of-rails-authentication-with-sessionuser-id),  session can be edited by user. But [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10355540/1066668) suggests it's safe to store user id.

From [Rails document](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore)

> A message digest is included with the cookie to ensure data integrity: a user cannot alter his user_id without knowing the secret key included in the hash

With `<%= debug(session) %>` embedded in my page and the session value in Chrome's Developer tools, I can't find the message digest in the session cookie. If I login as user A and then login as user B, the session cookie remains the same excecpt `user_id` value.

So where is the **message digest** or do I need some configuration? The auto-generated secret_token exists in `config/initializers/secret_token.rb`. Is it stored in the server's memory and hash the session value on every request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message digest is part of the cookie value. It's not part of the data you get in the session.

You can see it if you inspect the raw cookie value in chrome - the digest is separated from the payload by a '--'